# Where is the implementation of '$app->run()' in Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, lumen

I can't find where the implementation of `run()` method that is used on Lumen is defined. The one that can be seen [in the bootstrapping file](https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/c25833addaff0db442614f7539d22d66fd1919fb/public/index.php#L28):

```php
$app->run();
```

Where is this method defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined on `Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\RoutesRequests`.

If you take a look at `bootstrap/app.php` you'll see this:

```
$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    dirname(__DIR__)
);
```

So we know that `$app` is an instance of `Laravel\Lumen\Application`.

The method `run()` is not defined on this class, but if you look closely, you'll see this:

```
class Application extends Container
{
    use Concerns\RoutesRequests,
        Concerns\RegistersExceptionHandlers;
```

Those [traits define additional behaviour for the class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Specifically, on `Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\RoutesRequests` you'll find:

```php
/**
 * Run the application and send the response.
 *
 * @param  SymfonyRequest|null  $request
 * @return void
 */
public function run($request = null)
{
    $response = $this->dispatch($request);

    if ($response instanceof SymfonyResponse) {
        $response->send();
    } else {
        echo (string) $response;
    }

    if (count($this->middleware) > 0) {
        $this->callTerminableMiddleware($response);
    }
}
```